# how can use custom permission djangorestframework

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have a project and now i want add a my new endpoint to this project that response a json . this json is very simple  and not need to any serializer or queryset.but i dont know how i can use permision_class in this endpoint?second question is what is "obj" in `def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):` is?where is come from?tnx.

view.py:

```
class TeacherPostStatistic(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (ClassCoTeacherPermission, ClassOwnerPermission)

    def get_klass(self):
        class_id = self.kwargs['class_id']
        return Class.objects.get(id=class_id)

    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        klass = self.get_klass()
        response = Post.post_count_last7days(klass)
        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

model.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # some field 

    @classmethod
    def post_count_last7days(cls, klass):
        post_per_day_chart = {}
        for past_day in range(0, 7):
            count_post_in_past_day = cls.objects.filter(klass__exact=klass, create_date__date=date.today()-timedelta(days=past_day)).count()
            post_per_day_chart[past_day] = count_post_in_past_day
        return post_per_day_chart
```

permission.py:

```
# TODO: using raise inside permission class should be revised
class ClassCoTeacherPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("in coteachers: ",obj)
        return self.has_perm(user=request.user, klass=obj)

    @classmethod
    def has_perm(cls, user, klass):
        co_teacher = ClassCoTeacherMembership.objects.filter(klass=klass, co_teacher=user)
        if not co_teacher.exists():
            raise exc.UserIsNotCoTeacherOfTheClass
        return True

class ClassOwnerPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Object-level permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    Assumes the model instance has an `owner` attribute.
    """

    @classmethod
    def has_perm(cls, user, klass):
        return klass.owner == user

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("im in ",obj)
        return self.has_perm(request.user, obj)
```

if needed any changes to solve this problem let me know plz . like change `generics.RetrieveAPIVie` to `APIView` or `ViewSet` or etc .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `has_perm` method in both of the Permission Classes:

```
class ClassCoTeacherPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("in coteachers: ",obj)
        return self.has_perm(user=request.user, klass=obj)


    def has_perm(self, user, klass):
        co_teacher = ClassCoTeacherMembership.objects.filter(klass=klass, co_teacher=user)
        if not co_teacher.exists():
            raise exc.UserIsNotCoTeacherOfTheClass
        return True

class ClassOwnerPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Object-level permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    Assumes the model instance has an `owner` attribute.
    """

    def has_perm(self, user, klass):
        return klass.owner == user

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("im in ",obj)
        return self.has_perm(request.user, obj)
```

Because when you are calling them, you are using `self`, means you are calling them through object, but you declared them as classmethod, which should throw error. More information can be [**found here**](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/) on differences between classmethod and objectmethod.